# Allow only one entry of a model that uses "has_one" in Rails using Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

```
class User
 include Mongoid::Document
 has_one :profile
end

class Profile
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I can successfully create a profile that's associated with a user. However, it seems as though I can actually create many profiles that are associated with the User. How do I only allow one profile to be created per user? btw, I'm a newb, so feel free to suggest additional reading that might help.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but you should be able to create a unique index on the user_id field of profile to prevent multiple profile documents with the same user_id

```
index({ user_id: 1 }, { unique: true, name: "user_id_index" })
```

Comment: I've done this and the index has been created. However, I'm still able to create a second profile with the same user.

Comment: it looks like when the second profile get's created it is not associate with the user id, which is what the index is for. However, I want to be able to throw an error if someone tries to create a second profile.

Comment: Try creating the index at the database level: `rake db:mongoid:create_indexes`

Comment: I did that and the index is there. Also, when i create a second profile it doesn't get associated with the user. That seems to be the work of the index. I just want to throw an error on the client side when the user tries to create a new profile if they have one already.

Comment: In your controller, you should be able to check whether the current user has a profile (`if current_user.profile ...`) and if so, set a flash with the message `flash[:error] = "You already have a profile"`. The flash should be rendered somewhere in your application layout to display messages to your users whenever needed. If you need more specific information or code samples, post what you have so far in your controller and view.

Comment: I ended up doing `if current_user.profile.nil? #does not have profile else #has profile end` Is there a better way of doing it?